# How exactly do i preform basic operations involving complement sets when the universal set equals N (Natural Numbers)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If A = {2,4,6,8,10}  B = {1,3,5,7,9} **X or U** = N {1,2,3,...}

Find:

- A<sup>c</sup> ∩ B<sup>c</sup>
- A<sup>c</sup> - B<sup>c</sup>
- (A ∩ B)<sup>c</sup>

Since the compliment set of A is all the elements of the Universal set that are non-existent in A, and the Universal set in this example is equal to natural numbers (infinite), how do i list all the numbers, is there a specific way to do this or do i just write it as A<sup>c</sup> = {1,3,5,7,9,11,..}

Thanks,

Comment: You might find it a little easier if you first apply identities to the first and second ones (specifically, De Morgan's) to simplify it a bit. This should give you sets that are a bit nicer to describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can use [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).  For instance, the complement of $\{3,4,5\}$ can be written

$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid x < 3\} \cup \{x \in \mathbb{N} \mid x > 5 \} \enspace. $$

There are many variations on this notation, but the main idea is to define a set by the properties satisfied by its elements.  These properties are specified by formulae like $x \leq 10$ or $x = 2n+1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (to specify odd natural numbers).